# ACL - Where to configure custom userModel for authorize?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm having `Player` instead of default `User` model for my Auth.
I recently configured ACL for my app and while trying to do testing by `return false` in my `isAuthorized($player)` function, the following error occured:

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by
Array ( [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1 )
```

Isn't the `Aro0.model` suppose to be `Player`? I can't find where to change for `Auth->authorize`. `Auth-authenticate` works fine as I manage to login since there is a `userModel` option allow me to specify a custom Model for user login.

Here's My AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Acl',
        'RequestHandler',
        'Auth' => array(

            'authorize' => array(
                'controller',
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'),
            ),

            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Player',
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'),
                    )
                )
            ),
        );
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    function isAuthorized($player)
    {
        //var_dump($player); die;
        return false;
        return $this->Auth->loggedIn();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. it is to append `userModel` together with `actionPath`.

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array('actionPath' => 'controllers/', 'userModel' => 'Player'),
    'Actions',
    'Controller'
);
```