# ACL cakePHP error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl, cakephp-acl

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1 ) "

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace
```

My model name is Admin not user, I have set it in the Auth component configurations

```
public $components = array('Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'admins','action' => 'login'),
        'authError' => '<font color="red">Did you really think you are allowed to see that? If yes then login!</font>',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Admin',
                'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password')
            )
        )
    ), 'Session', 'Email');
```

I don't know how it is User not Admin in the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967707/acl-where-to-configure-custom-usermodel-for-authorize

Answer (score 1):

Please realise that **Authentication** is not the same as **Access Control**, although you properly configured your `AuthComponent` (Form) authentication to use the Admin model, the ACL may still be trying to access the User model.

For more information, please refer to the manual here;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html#assigning-permissions

And here;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#acts-as-a-requester

Especially, the 'model' column when assigning permissions and the section on 'requester'.

I realise this is not a full answer, I don't have the right examples at hand here, but maybe these suggestions will help you to find the solution.